# ActiveMQ Artemis: Disk filling indefinitely without consumers or producers

Tags: persistence, activemq-artemis

We are testing ActiveMQ Artemis 2.22.0 with clients using the core protocol. The broker is configured to apply paging. We let producers fill up the broker with messages until `max-disk-usage` stopped all producers.

After we tried connecting consumers, which worked in the first place. However, the brokers disk kept filling until the broker crashed completely.

Now, even after we disconnected all clients manually we see that after restart the broker is extending its message journal until the disk is full again. After restart we see a lot of  messages saying `deleting orphaned file`. The disk usage goes down. After some seconds however, the journal starts rising again and the story repeats.

That's probably not enough information to clearly solve our issue. Thus, here are my questions:

1. What are possible causes to fill disk space if neither consumers nor producers are connected?
2. How can we debug such a situation?
3. In case (really not hoping for that), the journal became corrupt. Is there any way first elaborate that and second restore it?

Comment: We are using solely the core protocol. We use version 2.22.0. We disconnected all clients manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are possible causes to fill disk space if neither consumers nor producers are connected?

You may be hitting [ARTEMIS-3868](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-3868) in which case I strongly recommend you move to the [latest release](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/download/) (i.e. 2.25.0 at this point).

> How can we debug such a situation?

The first thing to do would be to use the `artemis data print` command to print details about exactly what is in the journal. Hopefully that will shed light on what is causing the journal growth.

> In case (really not hoping for that), the journal became corrupt. Is there any way first elaborate that and second restore it?

Particular records in the journal may be corrupted and lost, but the broker should be able to read and recover everything that is still viable.

Comment: Yeah, it really looked strange. We now stopped the broker, exported the journal, and are about to reimport it. That seems to work fine. We are however not sure. If we lost messages that way. The original journal size was 38GB and the export is 2GB. We read, that the exporter is compacting. So our guess is that there was something wrong with the compaction.

We also have a copy of the original journal. If you're interested I could raise an GitHub issue and send you the files?!

Comment: I updated my answer with some additional info. I think you should upgrade to the latest version and see if the issue happens again.

Comment: Yeah, sounds a lot like what we were facing too. Thanks for the hint.